# How can I get the "Eclipse >Generate>Jaxb classes" option back?

Tags: java, eclipse, jaxb, xsd

I recently had to migrate to a new machine and re-installed Eclipse. 
At the moment, I need to generate JAXB classes from an xsd. I cannot quite remember what I installed, but in my old Eclipse I had the option -rightclick-generate-jaxb classes.

Who knows what I have to install/plug-in to get it back?

I was looking at installing [Dali](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?nav=%2F16), which seems like it could be right, but I am pretty sure I did not install Dali last time. I also included the jaxb jars in my build path, as last time, so that should be ok.

I am using Eclipse 3.6  and Java SE 1.6.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A simple fix for this problem - rather than worrying about adding additional plugins or installs - is to install **Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers** rather than **Eclipse Classic** (both to be found [here](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/)). This comes with the JAXB support and therefore provides the *>Generate>Jaxb classes* option.

Answer (score 17):

If you don't have JavaEE:

Help>>Install New Software>>Works with:--All Available Sites--

Search for JAXB

Then select Web, XML, Java EE and OSGi Enterprise Development and install.

After you restart Eclipse you should see the generate option.

Comment: This is the way to go if you want to just add JAXB Support. You only need to install `Dali Java Persistence Tools - JAXB Support`, not the whole group.

Answer (score 10):

The above methods may work, but actually the options comes from a plugin called **[Web Tools Platform](http://download.eclipse.org/webtools/downloads/)** which comes along with **Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers**.

Don't worry about reinstalling eclipse or try out other methods. No matter what eclipse you use simply install this plugin by following the below procedure. You will get the "**JAXB Classes**" Option on click of "**Generate**" button.

**Help** --> **Install New Software** --> **Add**

```
Name : Web Tools Platform
Location : http://download.eclipse.org/webtools/repository/helios
```

**Hint** : In case if you are using a different version replace helios with your eclipse version name. I used it as luna. So the path looks like http://download.eclipse.org/webtools/repository/luna

And **restart** eclipse. Now you will have that option.

Answer (score 3):

(I'm using IBM's Eclipse-based RAD, so I don't know whether this applies to raw Eclipse.)

Have a look at your project Facets (select project, rightClick->Properties, Project Facets) I have the option of selecting JAX/RS.

later: I've checked my plugins and by default I get Dali installed and it does contain some JAX/B-related stuff. I suspect you do need this.

Comment: thanks for the effort :) Turns out I didn't have the jaxb installed properly.

Answer (score 2):

I installed this plugin

http://java.net/downloads/jaxb-workshop/IDE%20plugins/jaxbw-plugin.zip

i.e. unzip and copy to eclipse/plugin folder.

It adds an entry "JAXB 2.1 > Run XJC" to the context menu of *.xsd files.

So the menu's not really in the proper place, but it works.

Answer (score 2):

After a lot of research here is what I have done to fix the issue.
Windows> Preferences> Java> InstalledJREs...make sure to point your jre to the jdk directory. I was pointing to JRE and as soon as I changed it to JDK, it started working.
Hope this will help you guys.

Answer (score 1):

In order to support the standard **JAXB APIs** in the **IntelliJ IDEA Community** Edition environment, you need to make some adjustments. One way to implement JAXB technology is to connect the xjc.exe utility included in the JDK toolkit. This utility can be launched at the command prompt, but it is **advisable** to configure the context menu:

- In the Settings window, select Tools | External Tools and press the
  "+" button.
- In the Edit Toolbox dialog enter:

  - the name `(Name :)` of the new Generate JAXB Classes command;
  - the path to the xjc.exe utility (Program :)`, which should be selected on the particular computer in the file selection dialog`(button "..." )`
  - parameters `(Parameters :)` which in our case will be as follows:

    `$ p $ FileFQPackage $ $ SourcepathEntry $ $ FilePath $`

In order for the created command to work correctly, the schema file should be placed in a new package, which will then appear with the generated files.

In the settings window, Tools | External Tools - "Your command name" will appear.
All you need is to open your schema file and run the command.

Answer (score 0):

you may download JAXB Eclipse Plug-In

[jaxb eclipse plugin](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jaxb-builder/postdownload?source=dlp)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue while attempting to generate java classes from xsd file.

My installed Eclipse is:
Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers
Version: Oxygen.3a Release (4.7.3a)

Build id: 20180405-1200

I solved it changing the workspace default JRE from JRE to JDK in Project Properties / Java Build Path / Libraries

This link describes how the problem arises:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zgblFjA-5Ks

This link explains how to change the default JRE.
https://www.zkoss.org/wiki/Setting_Default_JRE_In_Eclipse

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Eclipse EE all you have to do is switch your running environment from JRE to JDK and that should fix it. Windows -> Preference -> Java -> Installed JRE -> Add - > (Choose Standard VM) Then Select JDK! 
Then Execution Environments under Installed JRE select your JavaSE-1.8 or your version and also select JDK!